# How to Resolve “SplFileInfo:getSize()” error in laravel 6

Tags: image-upload, laravel-6

I am trying to update user profile picture. But each & everytime I am getting error like -

> RuntimeException SplFileInfo::getSize(): stat failed for /tmp/php8uXhSg

whenever I am doing **dd()** just before **save()** method, everything is looking good. But at the time of saving record it is throwing error.

Below are code of my controller -

**UserController.php**

```
public function update(UserRequest $request, $slug) {

   if($request->has('profile')) {
      $profile = $request->profile;
      $extension = $profile->getClientOriginalExtension();
      $profile_name = auth()->user()->username.time().'.'.$extension;
      $path = public_path('storage/uploads/avatars');
      $profile->move($path, $profile_name);

      auth()->user()->profile = $profile_name;
   }
   auth()->user()->save();

   return back()->with(['mesg', 'Successfully Uploaded.']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem some time ago, I checked upload_max_filesize / post_max_size and there should be no problem but the problem persists. Then I checked again on phpinfo to make sure and I tried to replace the save method with create and when I refreshed again suddenly the error is gone and I return it back to the save method and it still runs smoothly. I still don't know why

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem, uploading a 9KB file, in WAMP, PHP 7.3.5 and Laravel 6

I think the problem is not Laravel related, but maybe a PHP/WAMP thingy.
Changing the `upload_max_filesize` / `post_max_size` (thus forcing a restart of PHP) fixed the issue

Comment: but In my case after fixing  `upload_max_filesize` / `post_max_size` and restarting PHP it doesn't work. Throwing same issue. When I used `ini_get (post_max_size)` it is showing Old value (2 MB) instead of new one.